# How does std::make_tuple preserve std::string type when it is an r-value reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I am attempting to make my own `tuple` implementation for practice. I was trying to pass into my tuple a `std::string` that as a `rvalue`. However, I am unable to get the code to compile and am wondering how to fix this. I understand it decays to a `char * const`, and substituting that into my template params works, but when trying similar code with the the standard libraries version of `std::make_tuple(Args&&...)` it has no problem with the `rvalue reference`. So I am curious as to what I am missing in my implementation and how I can fix it. Detailed explanation would be appreciated for an in depth understanding.

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  //Tuple<int, int> int_tuple = custom_make_tuple(1, 2);
  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  std::string Testing = "testing";

  Tuple<int, int, char, std::string> t1 = makeTuple(1, b, 'c', "test"); //Fails to compile
  Tuple<int, int, char, std::string> t1 = makeTuple(1, b, 'c', Testing); //OK
  std::tuple<std::string> test = std::make_tuple("test"); //OK

  return 0;
}
```

tuple.h

```
template<typename... Types>
class Tuple;

// recursive case:
template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
class Tuple<Head, Tail...>
{
private:
  Head head;
  Tuple<Tail...> tail;
public:
  constexpr Tuple() {
  }

  template<typename FHead, typename... FTail>
  constexpr Tuple(FHead && head, FTail &&... tail)
    : head(std::forward<FHead>(head)), tail(std::forward<FTail>(tail)...) {}

  constexpr Head& GetHead() { return head; }
  constexpr Head const& GetHead() const { return head; }
  constexpr Tuple<Tail...>& GetTail() { return tail; }
  constexpr Tuple<Tail...> const& GetTail() const { return tail; }
};

// basis case:
template<>
class Tuple<> {};

template<typename... Eles>
constexpr auto makeTuple(Eles&&... elems)
{
  return Tuple<std::decay_t<Eles>...>(std::forward<Eles>(elems)...);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeTuple(1, b, 'c', "test")` returns a `Tuple<int, int, char, const char*>`.  You then try to copy-construct a `Tuple<int, int, char, std::string>` from that tuple, which doesn't work, because `Tuple<int, int, char, std::string>`'s constructor expects arguments of type `int`, `int`, `char`, and `std::string`, not a `Tuple<int, int, char, const char*>`.

You need to add converting constructors that will accept a tuple and convert the contained objects to the types you need:

```
template <typename... Types>
friend class Tuple;

template<typename FHead, typename... FTail,
         std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Tail) + 1 == sizeof...(FTail) + 1>* = nullptr>
constexpr Tuple(const Tuple<FHead, FTail...>& o)
  : head(o.head), tail(o.tail)
{}

template<typename FHead, typename... FTail,
         std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Tail) + 1 == sizeof...(FTail) + 1>* = nullptr>
constexpr Tuple(Tuple<FHead, FTail...>&& o)
  : head(std::move(o.head)), tail(std::move(o.tail))
{}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e97588ced211481b)

Note that the `std::enable_if_t` parameter exists to avoid having the converting constructors chosen when you're actually trying to create a `Tuple` that contains a single `Tuple`.